# Validar cantidad de campos y que tenga registros archivo csv

Tags: php

Quiero validar:
1) Que el archivo CSV tenga la cantidad de campos que se requieren (en mi caso 6).
2) Que el archivo CSV tenga por lo menos un registro para trabajar.
No necesito validar que el archivo exista.
El siguiente código muestra la cantidad de campos por registro que tiene el archivo CSV.

```
<?php
$fila = 1;
$gestor = fopen("C:\archivo.csv", "r")
    while (($datos = fgetcsv($gestor, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $numero = count($datos);
        echo "$numero de campos en la línea $fila </br>";
        $fila++;
    }
fclose($gestor);
?>
```

Quiero simplificar el código para lograr lo que indiqué. El archivo contiene cabecera.

Comment: Tu código funciona y poco más se puede hacer con él, ¿qué necesitas exactamente? ¿compactarlo? ¿convertirlo en función? ¿en clase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es crearte una función que haga las siguientes comprobaciones:

- Más de una línea de datos.
- Todos los registros deben tener seis campos.

Esta función te podría servir:

```
function comprobar_csv($archivo) {
  $n = 0;
  if (!file_exists($archivo)) {
    /* Decidir qué hacer en caso de que no exista el archivo */
    return false;
  }
  $fh = @fopen($archivo, 'r');
  if ($fh === false) {
    /* Decidir qué hacer en caso de error de apertura */
    return false;
  }
  while (($datos = fgetcsv($fh, 1000, ',')) !== false && ++$n) {
    /* En caso de no tener 6 campos cerramos y salimos */
    if (count($datos) != 6) {
      fclose($fh);
      return false;
    }
  }
  fclose($fh);
  /* Comprobamos que tenga al menos una línea */
  return $n > 0;
}
/* Ejemplo de uso */
var_dump(comprobar_csv('ejemplo.csv'));
```

Comment: Suponiendo que el archivo csv contenga cabecera y quiero contar los registros data. Cambiaría $n = 1?

Comment: Cambié la última línea de esta manera: if (var_dump(comprobar_csv('ejemplo.csv'))) { /* Si es True hace esto / } else { / Si es False hace esto */ } Pero cuando cuando el archivo tiene o no registros no entra al bucle True.

Comment: No, cambiarías `$n > 1`. `$n = 1` es una asignación, no una comparación. En cuanto al segundo comentario, quita `var_dump()` y te funcionará. Es una herramienta de depuración, no es necesaria para usar la función que te hice. Sería `if (comprobar_csv('...') ...`.

Comment: Hola @OscarGarcia ¿Si necesitara comparar el encabezado del archivo (Suponiendo que necesito que tenga 5 campos: Nombre, Apellido1, Apellido2, Email, Celular) ¿Como se hace la comparación del encabeado? (Tomando en cuenta las validaciones ya establecidas.) Gracias.

Comment: Hola @NeftaliAcosta , no entiendo bien el escenario que quieres plantearme. ¿Podrías hacer el favor de detallarlo con algún ejemplo? Si has creado una pregunta nueva déjame aquí el enlace.